# How can I make VOIP Call from Website to Mobile Device?

Tags: php, laravel, web, voip

I need to make a VOIP call from my website to a mobile device. I tried using Twilio. But it seems it doesn't work in India. And the Twilio support is not giving appropriate response.

Can anyone suggest me a possible solution for this.

There are two end users here. One is the principal of a school, and the other one is a teacher. Principal is using a website, and teacher is using a mobile device. We need to give a platform to the principal to make a call to the teacher, through its browser. We are using PHP/Laravel as back end.

Comment: you can use  parahittech.com these also provide the API

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has a working sample on how to achieve this in Laravel.

[Twilio Browser to Mobile Call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/browser-calls-php-laravel)

[Github Repository for laravel sample](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-laravel.git)